# Android App crashes when trying to do setText on TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I have used setText lot of times but now when ever i try to do setText i get

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference**

```
 public View getView(int position, View conver, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ac_layout, null);
        }
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.venue_image);
            icon.setImageResource(sportsMap.get(sportList.get(position).getId()));
            TextView venueName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.venue_name);
            //Toast.makeText(context,venueList.get(position).getVenueName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            venueName.setText(sportList.get(position).getDisplayName());
            TextView Place = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.place);
            Place.setText("sad");

        return convertView;
    }
```

Here the error occurs at line  **Place.setText("sad");**

i do not get errors anywhere else, only in that **Place.setText("sad");** i get error.

I have declared the TextView in my xml. I just dont knw why is my app crashing.

I genuinely expect helpful answers.

Comment: could you please post the Logcat too..

Comment: Also, if you can, please post `sport_listitem.xml` file too..

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake i mistook wrong file in convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sport_listitem, null); Thanks Lal

Comment: ok, but my qstn is aldy downvoted :-/

Comment: Oh @codeMagic..Sorry that i didnt do it yet.. I dont have enough reps to close a question..I can only vote to close and usually close votes on these type of questions gets declined..

Comment: @codeMagic let this qstn be there as ppl will know that this error was caused by accessing wrong layout

Comment: I've already voted it.. @codeMagic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not inflating the correct xml file as you don't have a TextView with id `place` in `sport_listitem.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your layout file you are inflating `sport_listitem.xml` there is no `TextView` with `android:id="@+id/place"`